# How to read textfile for setting value based on another in same row

Tags: c#, text-files

I am accessing a text file which has values in a column, rows format so first line is columns and rest all corresponding rows.

I have one condition like if column name is `BSC` and its value is `BSC37` or `BSC38` I have to set value like `region_code = "AUH";`. If value is `BSCN10` then `region_code` can be `AUH` or `DBL`, so here another value for a column name "LAC" ==3 then region_code is 'AUH' otherwise if "LAC"==4 then `region_code` is 'DXB'.

I got stuck to achieve it since these values are coming in same row and sequentially.

Here is what I did so far:

```
string[] cols = lines[0]
    .Trim()
    .Split(new[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int liness = 1;
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(2))
{
    string[] cells = line
        .Trim()
        .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < cols.Length; counter++)
    {
        string cellValue = "N/A";
        if (counter < cells.Length)
            cellValue = cells[counter];

        if (cols[counter] == "BSC")
        {               
            insvalues2gericson.Add(new FormField("BSC_ID", cellValue, 2));
            if (cellValue == "BSC37" || cellValue == "BSC38" )
            {
                region_code = "AUH";
            }
            else
            if (cellValue == "BSCN10")
            {
               //here i need to coding
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please poste your text file?

Comment: if you know exactly the column indexes (header?) and you load the data per row, why don't you go directly to the relevant indexes and check their values instead of iterating over all the cells?
for example lets assume you know that index 5 is `BSC` col, just go to `row[5]` and check the value. the same goes for the rest of the conditions. by accessing each column directly their order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. Put the first row in a list of columns. Go through the remaining rows, putting each row in a list of cells. Then, get the index of a certain column by column name (e.g. `columns.IndexOf("BSC")` to get the cell value. That way you can easily access the cell values of both columns `BSC` and `LAC`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var text = "BSC,LAC" + Environment.NewLine
            + "BSC37,1" + Environment.NewLine
            + "BSC38,2" + Environment.NewLine
            + "BSCN10,3"+ Environment.NewLine
            + "BSCN10,4";

        var rows = text.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        var columns = rows[0].Split(',').ToList();

        foreach(var row in rows.Skip(1)) {
            var cells = row.Split(',');

            string regionCode = "";

            if(cells[columns.IndexOf("BSC")] == "BSC37" 
              || cells[columns.IndexOf("BSC")] == "BSC38") { 
                regionCode = "AUH";
            }

            if(cells[columns.IndexOf("BSC")] == "BSCN10")
            {
                if(cells[columns.IndexOf("LAC")] == "3") {
                    regionCode = "AUH";
                } 
                if(cells[columns.IndexOf("LAC")] == "4") 
                    regionCode = "DXB";
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}->{2}",cells[0],cells[1], regionCode);
        }
    }
}
```